# Visual Basic: Changing a Button Click into a Constantly Updating Event

Tags: .net, vb.net, timer, activex, updates

I'm new to Visual Basic (I'm learning it to build part of a project for a client). Below is sample code that is using the Sterling ActiveX API library. Basically, this program runs alongside a stock-trading software called Sterling Trader and, when the button is pressed, the text box updates with the current stock quote of the specified stock (in this case it's IBM):

```
Option Strict Off
Option Explicit On

Public Class Form1
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

Dim stiEvents As New SterlingLib.STIEvents
Dim stiQuote As New SterlingLib.STIQuote

Delegate Sub TextBoxUpdater(ByVal byre As TextBox, ByRef str As Object)

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    AddHandler stiQuote.OnSTIQuoteSnap, AddressOf OnSTIQuoteSnap
    AddHandler stiQuote.OnSTIQuoteUpdate, AddressOf OnSTIQuoteUpdate
End Sub

Private Sub OnSTIQuoteSnap(ByRef structQuoteSnap As SterlingLib.structSTIQuoteSnap)

    UpdateTextBoxLast(TextBox1, structQuoteSnap.fLastPrice)

End Sub

Private Sub OnSTIQuoteUpdate(ByRef structQuoteUpdate As SterlingLib.structSTIQuoteUpdate)

    If structQuoteUpdate.bLastPrice Then
        UpdateTextBoxLast(TextBox1, structQuoteUpdate.fLastPrice)
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub UpdateTextBoxLast(ByVal lb As TextBox, ByRef str As Object)
    If (lb.InvokeRequired) Then
        Me.BeginInvoke(New TextBoxUpdater(AddressOf UpdateTextBoxLast), lb, str)
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = str

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    stiQuote.RegisterQuote("IBM", "*")
End Sub

End Class
```

Link to the Sterling Activex API guide: http://www.sterlingtrader.com/documents/Sterling_ActiveX_API_Guide.pdf

Two things I'd like to do this code:

1. I want to do is make the text box constantly update itself with the new current stock quote without the button being pressed. I'm guessing you could do this with a timer, but I'm not entirely certain what section of the code to modify, nor am I familiar with the way to do this in Visual Basic.
2. I'd like to create another text box/button that let's you change the stock whose quote you are pulling by typing it in and clicking the button. Right now, the code is using the IBM stock; this is determined by the "IBM" part of this line of code: stiQuote.RegisterQuote("IBM", "*")

How can I do these two things?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of a timer and a programmatic button click.

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms ' one of several namespaces that include timers

Public Class MyForm

    Private MyTimer As Timer

    Private Sub MyForm_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        MyTimer = New Timer
        MyTimer.Interval = 1000 ' 1 second
        MyTimer.Enabled = True
        AddHandler MyTimer.Tick, AddressOf HandleTimer
    End Sub

    Private Sub HandleTimer()
        Button1.PerformClick()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles     Button1.Click
        TextBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM:ss")  
    End Sub

    Private Sub MyForm_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
        MyTimer.Dispose()
        MyTimer = Nothing
    End Sub

End Class
```